# Hibernate query into ArrayList

Tags: java, hibernate

I am very new to Java and Hibernate and after being taken from a Unix background to be handed a Java project with problems I need assistance please.

The project currently has Hibernate set up with criteria to search a database of document meta-data and currently assumes a "Unique Result", with this line of code;

```
doc = (DocumentDetails) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Meaning, I think, it expects only one document's details as a result.  But we now can have multiple possible documents' details returned and I need to place them into an `ArrayList` to determine which one is the latest document.

Any assistance would be appreciated on how to do this.  I apologise for me being forward but I need to solve this one quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<DocumentDetails> doc = (ArrayList<DocumentDetails>) criteria.list();
```

Comment: Hi Szajba, thanks for that.  Do you mean simply replacing the line of code I listed above with this one will place all results into the ArrayList?

Comment: Yes you will get an ArrayList of DocumentDetails objects

Answer (score 4):

```
List<DocumentDetails> result = criteria.list();
```

As simple as that. Hibernate [is documented](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html).